# Appending DataFrame to existing layer in GeoPackage

Tags: geopandas, geopackage, data-frame

I have scripts to download and extract two shapefiles every 24 hours and create a cleaned DataFrame. I want to append the DataFrame for each one to a specific layer in a gpkg. The only example I can find replaces the contents of the existing layer, but I want to append the new df each day to an existing layer (of two total layers in the pgkg)

This is the snippet I have so far:

```py
df.to_file("myfile.gpkg", layer="layer1", driver="GPKG")
```

Comment: try appending using mode='a' i.e `df.to_file(etc..., mode='a')` https://stackoverflow.com/a/63491963/737471 (note linked answer shows GPKG does not support append, but [fiona source](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/blob/master/fiona/drvsupport.py#L63) show it does, so you may need a very recent version of fiona).

Answer (score 4):

You can read the geopackage file and append the dataframe and then re-write it:

```
gdf_base = gpd.read_file("myfile.gpkg", layer='layer1')
gdf_base = gdf_base.append(df,ignore_index=True)
gdf_base .to_file("myfile.gpkg", layer="layer1", driver="GPKG")
```

If your data is too big to be read every day, then you need to look for Spatialite coding to append your data.

**UPDATE!**

The append method is going to be depricated. Use `concat` instead:

```
gdf_base = gpd.read_file("myfile.gpkg", layer='layer1')
gdf_base = pd.concat([gdf_base,df],ignore_index=True)
gdf_base .to_file("myfile.gpkg", layer="layer1", driver="GPKG")
```

Answer (score 2):

[geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_file](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_file.html) can take the keyword argument mode set to 'a' in order to append data to a file:

```
gdf_base.to_file("myfile.gpkg", layer="layer1", driver="GPKG", mode='a')
```

Answer (score 1):

From what i red from the [docs](https://geopandas.org/docs/user_guide/mergingdata.html) this should be half ccomplished with

```
df.geometry.append(another_red_df.geometry)
```

I don't think that the data will be added too. Here you can look further in the docs for joining values by attributes.